# The best database solution for cashier machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

I'm developing a cashier machine which handle more than 20 transactions per day, I want your suggestion for database that suite my need. Which is the best between sql server express or sql server ce in case of maintainability and effectivity.  Sorry for a newbie question but I need your help. Thanks.

Comment: 20 transactions per day? As in, less than 1 per hour (on average)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Less than 1 per hour, LOL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to choose the best database version of MS SQL Server for your needs then just read this site: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions.aspx.

A good blog post about the smaller version is here: http://erikej.blogspot.de/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html

Answer (score 1):

Express version is designed to be installed, and Compact version in designed to be bundled in your application, which means developers can distribute them in the application.

So if you're developing for a company, embed compact edition in your end product. And also, SQL Compact don't have a separate process, it runs with your process.

On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact):

> Unlike other editions of Microsoft SQL Server, SQL CE runs in-process with the application which is hosting it.

Also, database size limit could be a problem. SQL CE hosts 4 GB only, while Express 2008 R2 and up can handle 10 GB. But the small database size also means lower memory footprint, usually 5 MB for CE (again from Wikipedia), and up to 1 GB for EE.

Compact Edition is 2 MB in size, while Express installs a server. Express runs on multiple core on a single physical processor.